# Writing parquet output with selected attributes from Bean

Tags: dataset, schema, parquet, apache-spark-2.0, kryo

I have a bean class

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Employee {
    String id;
    String name;
    String depart;
    String address;
    final String pipe= "|";

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return id +pipe+ name +pipe+depart;
    }
}
```

And I have a `JavaRDD<Employee> emprdd;`
and when I do the `emprdd.saveAsText(path);`. I get the output as based on the toString method.
Now I wanted to write into the parquet format  after converting it to the dataframe but I need only (`id,name,depart`). I tried `sqlContext.createDataframe(rdd,Employee.class);` (syntax ignored), but I dont need all the properties.

Can anyone guide me through this. (This is a sample , I have bean class with 350+ attributes)